# How to select the most k distant elements

Tags: algorithm

Part of my research is selecting k elements that are most distant among n elements. Assume the following example:

```
      T1   T2   T3   T4   T5
T1    -    5    2    7    3
T2    5    -    6    2    8
T3    2    6    -    9    1
T4    7    2    9    -    4
T5    3    8    1    4    -
```

I want to select the three most distant elements. Note that each number represents the distance between any two elements such as the distance between T1 and T2 is 5.

One way I thought about is to sum the distance for each element and based on that I select the highest three sum values. Applying this to the example shown above results in:

```
T1    T2    T3    T4    T5
17    21    18    22    16
```

Based on this, the three most distant elements are T4, T2, and T3.

Do you think the correct way to select k most distant elements or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: If you consider that the most distant element is the one whose sum of the distances to all the other elements is the biggest, than your approach seems ok.

Comment: @Daniel Is it possible to apply the greedy algorithm in my case?

Comment: You should detail what you call the most distant elements. With your algorithm, you select elements distant from all the others, but the selected elements could be very near one to each other. Is it an issue?

Comment: @Damien No, it's not issue. Basically, I want to know a way to find how far an element is from the other elements. I am interested in finding those elements that are the most far elements from the rest of elements. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends on what you mean by "most distant".  Which in turn depends on your research application.  Not knowing that, I can't even advise you about the appropriate definition to use.  Or even about whether you are thinking about it in a useful way.  Nor can anyone else.

(Though https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality is worth being aware of.  If it applies in any way, your intuition is likely to mislead you.)

Comment: Can you please see my reply to Damien?

Comment: @AdamAmin Do you want the sum of the distances maximized?  The median distance maximized?  Do you want to find a group of "average elements" and find things that look as little like that group as possible?  These are all reasonable things that you could mean, and which one you actually want strongly depends on what your research problem is.

Comment: To explain the research problem, each element is a test case and the distance between any two test cases is the hamming distance calculated based on the difference in their statements. The higher the distance, the higher the difference in the statements of the two test cases.